# Azure Data Factory Lookup activity fail to execute CosmosDb query 'Cross partition query only supports 'VALUE ' for aggregates.'

Tags: azure

I am trying to configure Azure Data Factory Lookup activity to get MAX datetime field value from CosmosDb container. But unfortunately simplest query just totally doesn't work, the query is

```
SELECT max(members.lastModifiedOn) as dt FROM members
```

In CosmosDb control panel we see results

```
[
    {
        "dt": "2020-09-01T07:32:03.6733333"
    }
]
```

But in Azure Data Factory preview we see nothing but error

```
One or more errors occurred.
Message: {"Errors":["Cross partition query only supports 'VALUE ' for aggregates."]}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only one trick which I've found is to execute query for Lookup activity in such weird format

```
SELECT VALUE r FROM (SELECT MAX(m.lastModifiedOn) as lastModifiedOn FROM m) as r
```

Seems Azure Data Factory Lookup activity is expecting to have array of object as the result of query execution